# Why is the text upside down?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot

I implemented [corePlot](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot) into my `xcode` project. I'm trying to add the `legend` [image] to another `cell`.

I'm able to add the `legend` to another cell, but when I do that, the text is upside down.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)configureLegend
{
    CPTGraph *graph = self.hostView.hostedGraph;
    CPTLegend *theLegend = [CPTLegend legendWithGraph:graph];

    // Add legend to graph
    graph.legend = theLegend;
    graph.legendAnchor = CPTRectAnchorRight;
    CGFloat legendPadding = - (self.chartView.bounds.size.width / 8);
    graph.legendDisplacement = CGPointMake(legendPadding, 0.0);

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:0]];
    [cell.layer addSublayer:graph.legend];
```

This is what I tried:

```
    theLegend.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI / 180.0f, 0, 1, 0);
}
```

That didn't do anything. The results where the same. Why is this happening, and how can I get the text to show normally, not upside down?

**Edit**

This is how it shows when I add it as a subLayer:[image] (It says: "First", "Second".)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Core Plot applies a flip transform on iOS so we can use the same drawing code on both the Mac and iOS. This is the transform it uses:

```
self.layer.sublayerTransform = CATransform3DMakeScale( CPTFloat(1.0), CPTFloat(-1.0), CPTFloat(1.0) );
```

Comment: I did cell.layer.sub.... and everything else in it went upside down. I then tried theLegend.layer.sub.... and it said I can't do .layer???

Comment: The legend *is* a `CALayer`. Set the `transform` on it directly.

Comment: I tried `theLegend.sublayer...` and it didn't do anything to the legend

Comment: As the name says, the `sublayerTransform` only affects the sublayers. Set the `transform` to affect the layer and its sublayers.

Answer (score 0):

Try `M_PI / 2.0f`  which is in radians.  Using 180.0f (presumably degrees) does not make sense in the context of this function.

Comment: Still doesn't work. I think the problem is, the way i try accessing the legend. cuz whatever value I input, it doesn't change.